# Testing HTTP requests in node.js with express

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, xmlhttprequest, express

I have a simple authentication system I've made with a few post/get/dels on '/session' using express.  I'd like to test this, but I can't seem to find a good easy way to simply test `http.sendPut('/session', {data})` from the server.  Does anyone have suggestions for a library to use?

I'm using Mocha/should for my tests, if that helps.

Here is my super simple auth-thingy that I want to test (it hooks into some other things):

```
//Login
app.post("/session", function(req, res) {
  if (req.body.username === "admin" && req.body.password === "admin") {
    req.session.user = "user";
    res.send("Successfully logged in!");
  } else {
    res.send(403, "Invalid username or password.");
  }
});
//Logout
app.del("/session", function(req, res) {
  req.session.user = null;
  res.send("Successfully logged out.");
});
//Am I logged in? Check for the client
app.get("/session", function(req, res) {
  if (req.session.user) {
    res.send(req.session.user);
  } else {
    res.send(403, "You are not logged in.");
  }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/mikeal/request is pretty popular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Express.js is tested with [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) and supertest is based on [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent).

If you need some examples you can find them in the Express.js [test code](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/test).

All the tests that require `request = require('./support/http');` are using supertest.

Comment: Well, using this so far and I need a way to check req.session after I send the http request. I can't seem to find any support for this in superagent or supertest, any ideas?

Comment: I don't think that is possible with supertest. It's more of a black box style of testing and sessions don't live directly in the http request. You probably want a more unit test style of testing where you test the middleware (function(req, res)) and check the state of req or res. I have a helper module that I use to do this in my projects. https://github.com/Enome/express-recorder/blob/master/specs/middleware.js Maybe you can get some ideas from that.